# Elasticsearch implementation in CS-Cart

Tags: php, elasticsearch, search, cs-cart

I have Elasticsearch up and running on my vps and i can check it by curl localhost:9200 but how to implement it with CS-CART ? new in cs-cart is there any config file where i have to make connection ?

Answer (score 0):

There are no such options for CS-Cart, the only thing I can recommend is that you make the appropiate changes to the /app/functions/fn.search.php file.

Do mind that elasticsearch requires that objects are pushed there. Furthermore, it will require certain modifications to CS-Cart's ajax for search.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, CS-Cart operates with MySQL as database. Custom integration is needed.

By the way, there is the https://start.searchanise.com/ service and plugin for CS-Cart which works via Sphinx